# How to retrieve data from Firebase realtime android to web app

Tags: javascript, android, html, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the data in my android firebase database, I would like to obtain the 'users' details and Uid.

Database structure: users/Uid

```
    {  "users" : {
"BbvZI5bKbXUNmK63ylJVIME6Kon1" : {
  "add1" : "2,jalan zakaria",
  "add2" : "lorong rahidin 2",
  "city" : "Sungai Buloh",
  "email" : "angah_gurly95@yahoo.com.my",
  "fullname" : "muhammad zafar darwisy",
  "ic" : "140223142397",
  "phoneNo" : "0123456789",
  "state" : "SELANGOR",
  "zipcode" : "60400"
},
"irNx5mxH47N26BzmsYBXYAF1dY82" : {
  "add1" : "34, dtrn rapat jaya",
  "add2" : "taman silibin",
  "city" : "Ipoh",
  "email" : "norhananisubri@gmail.com",
  "fullname" : "nor hanani subri",
  "ic" : "123",
  "phoneNo" : "0175",
  "state" : "PERAK",
  "zipcode" : "31350"
}}}
```

Below is the code that I am using to obtain 'users' by using their firebase userID.
Javascript:

```
// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function() {  
var rootRef= firebase.database().ref().child("users");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
var name= snap.child("fullname").val();
var ic = snap.child("ic"),val();
var email= snap.child("email").val();
var phoneNo= snap.child("phoneNo").val();
var add1= snap.child("add1").val();
var add2= snap.child("add2").val();
var city= snap.child("city").val();
var zipcode= snap.child("zipcode").val();
var state= snap.child("state").val();


$("#table_data").append("<tr><td>" + name +
 "</td><td>" + ic + "</td><td>" + ic +
 "</td><td>" + email + "</td><td>" + phoneNo +
 "</td><td>" + add1 + "</td><td>" + add2 +
 "</td><td>" + city + "</td><td>" + zipcode +
 "</td><td>" + state + "</td><td><button>Remove</button></td></tr>"); 
//alert(snap.val());

});

});
```

However, I am still unable to obtain the 'users' for a user with userID, can someone please suggest where I am going wrong ?
I also want to display the userID, how should i write it?
I want those data display in my web admin, means i have a database from android and want to display it in web app.

This is the HTML code

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody id=table_data>
          <thead>
            <tr>
             <!-- <th>ID No</th>-->
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>IC</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Phone No</th>
              <th>Address 1</th>
              <th>Address 2</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>ZIP Code</th>
              <th>State</th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try this `var userID = snap.key;`

You can see detail at Firebase doc here [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key)

I see that you use arrow function, so why don't you try [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this

```
$("#table_data").append(`
    <tr>
        <td>${userID}</td>
        <td>${name}</td>
        <td>${ic}</td>
        <td>${ic}</td>
        <td>${email}</td>
        <td>${phoneNo}</td>
        <td>${add1}</td>
        <td>${add2}</td>
        <td>${city}</td>
        <td>${zipcode}</td>
        <td>${state}</td>
        <td><button>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
`);
```